# Are Apache Tika's LanguageDetectors thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, apache-tika, language-detection

Consider the following code:

```
final String[] texts = {
    "Allons, enfants de la Patrie, Le jour de gloire est arrivé",
    "O Tannenbaum, o Tannenbaum, wie treu sind deine Blätter!",
    "..."
};

final LanguageDetector ld = new OptimaizeLangDetector();  // or e.g. OpenNLPDetector
ld.loadModels();
Arrays.stream(texts).parallel().forEach(text -> System.out.println(ld.detect(text)));
```

Can I assume that `ld.detect()` and `ld.detectAll()` are thread-safe and can be ran in parallel on multiple texts using a single `LanguageDetector` instance?

The thing that makes me worry is that `LanguageDetector` has methods like `addText()`, `hasEnoughText()` and `reset()` which make it stateful, and therefore - by definition - non-thread-safe...

https://tika.apache.org/2.7.0/api/org/apache/tika/language/detect/LanguageDetector.html

Comment: Looks like the intent is certainly that they are :  “Detect and parse are both thread-safe. If you find otherwise, that's a bug! ”   https://www.mail-archive.com/user@tika.apache.org/msg03473.html

Comment: @racraman The post you linked refers to class `org.apache.tika.Tika`, which is used to detect media types, not to `org.apache.tika.language.detect.LanguageDetector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A requirement for a class to be thread-safe, is that it is immutable. That means after construction, instance methods are not allowed to change any members.

When reading the source for `org.apache.tika.langdetect.optimaize.OptimaizeLangDetector` [here](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-langdetect/tika-langdetect-optimaize/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/langdetect/optimaize/OptimaizeLangDetector.java)

we'll see this instance method

```
public void reset() {
    writer.reset();
}
```

which is changing member

```
private CharArrayWriter writer;
```

and with that the state of the `OptimaizeLangDetector` instance. Hence `OptimaizeLangDetector` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thank you @Roar S.! This is what I expected. However, it seems that Optimaize Language Detector, when used on its own (outside of Tika), IS thread-safe...

https://github.com/optimaize/language-detector/issues/9